# Layer masking in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to achieve a similar effect to this

[image: clipping example]

I know how to do the background image and all that. But the blue circle is suppose to be an image with a layer mask around it, so you could see through to the background image. The grey div to the left would just overlap behind it. I'm not sure how to achieve the masking effect though, I've done some research into it [here](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/), but I am having trouble telling what would be useful to get effect I am trying to achieve. Anyone have any ideas as to how I could code this out?

Comment: Why not have the blue circle and the grey box as one picture with the space between being transparent?

Comment: Concave masking seems like a tough case. If you can find a how-to for that, the rest is easy enough.

Comment: You've tagged this question with SVG. Are you opposed to building it in Illustrator? https://css-tricks.com/using-svg

Comment: @Vlad Bardalez I might do that if this was a self project, but I need this template to require the barest of stuff done- So people who i hand this off too should be able to look at this template and enter text into the grey box, and a image in the blue box. Rather then having to open up a program and make a picture. (as these people don't know how to do that).

Comment: @isherwood I tagged it as SVG since it may be a part of the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this I guess.

```css
* { margin:0; padding: 0; }
body {
  background: url('http://www.bestmanspeechestoasts.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-4.jpg');
}
p { padding: 0 10px; font-size: 12px; color:#fff; line-height: 1.3; overflow: hidden; }
.outer {
  margin: 50px auto;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.box:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -25px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 350px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
.outer:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="box"><p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How did you add the code snippet like that? Is that a new feature?

Comment: @iMoses I think it's a half year old already, but it may be called new. :)

Comment: Well, it's being a while since I last answered questions here. Nevertheless, very cool feature, indeed handy. Just wondering why Babkbone isn't a default library and Knockout is :)

Comment: @drip This is super close, i need to also put text in a p tag inside the black div though, is that possible? It doesn't look like it is with the box shadow but i may be wrong.

Comment: @smilefreak24 there is now text as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might get you started:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container"> 
  <div id="gray-box" class="clip-circle"></div>
  <div id="blue-circle">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clip-circle {
  clip-path: circle(5px at 0px 15px);
}
#gray-box {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #AAA;
  width: 300px;
  height: 60px;
}
#blue-circle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 13px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dobbwQ